# How to client's Public IP address using Request.UserHostAddress in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying the retrieve the Client IP Address ie Client's Public address using the Request.UserHostAddress. But it returning the different IP.  If I try getting the Client's Public IP using external site like https://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=? . I am getting the correct the Public IP.

Right now, I am able to get the client IP address using the external site, but its not feasible to relie on the external URL.

Please help me how to get the client IP Address using Request.UserHostAddress

Comment: What do you intend to *do* with this information? Practically, the client's IP is usually a transient detail with which not a lot can be done.

Comment: I will need to send the IPAddress to a thrid party to get authenticate into their site